# How to create a reference from one portlet to another?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I am using  **Spring portlet MVC framework** with **Oracle WebLogic Portal**.

I have a page with a few portlets. For example `page#1` (contains 2 portlets - `portlet#1` and `portlet#2`) and another page - `page#2` with two more portlets (`portlet#3` and `portlet#4`)

The first portlet on the first page (`portlet#1`) contains a link. I want to go to the page which belongs to the `portlet#3` (is located on another page !!!).

**How can I do this ?**

To create a connection between two portlets within one page (which contain these portlets) is not a problem. **But is it possible to move between different portlets which are localed on different pages ???**

Comment: i guess you can use IPC

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question [Spring Portlet MVC sentRedirect and setRenderParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158862/spring-portlet-mvc-sentredirect-and-setrenderparameter)

You could use a redirect in portlet#1 to link to page#2

*Portlet Controller portlet#1*

```
@ActionMapping("doGotoPage2")
public void doGoToPage2(ActionRequest req,
    ActionResponse resp) {

 try {
    resp.sendRedirect("/url/to/page#2");
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DefaultViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
}
```

and also set an attribute to PortletSession

```
 PortletSession session = req.getPortletSession();
 session.setAttribute("key", "value", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Then you can read the PortletSession in portlet#3 and handle it accordingly

*PortletController portlet#3*

```
PortletSession session = req.getPortletSession();
String sessionKey= (String) session.getAttribute("key", PORTLET_SESSION_SCOPE);
```